# Reading a file in Servlet and Splitting the String

Tags: java

I'm trying to read a file in a servlet, this is done by this code:

```
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream("/AFINN-111.txt");

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
PrintWriter pw = resp.getWriter();

String text = "";
```

I'm trying to split a string, for example:

good 2

excellent 3

The strings always has an english word and a numeric value, and I'm trying to store these values in a `ArrayList`, for example:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Now, the problem is when I'm trying to split the values:

```
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    resp.getWriter().println(text +  "<br />");

    resp.getWriter().println("<br />");
    String[] split_text = text.split(" ");
    //resp.getWriter().println(split_text.length +  "<br />");

    for(int j = 0 ; j < split_text.length; j++)
    {
        resp.getWriter().println(split_text[j] + " <br />");
    }
    resp.getWriter().println("<br />");
    resp.getWriter().println("<br />");

}
```

String: good 2

Split outcome: good 2

length: 1

When I tried to split the string by space, I get the same string back.

Text file list is found at: http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/6010/zip/imm6010.zip

Solution: Use .split("\t");

Thanks again for everyone's help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the text file are separated with a tab from the words.
This should give you the expected result:

```
String[] split_text = text.split("\t");
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `text` variable has "good&nbsp2" instead of "good 2"

`good&nbsp2` looks like `good 2` on browser, cause `&nbsp` represents `single space` in HTML

EDIT: You can say `text.split("&nbsp;");` to still split them

Comment: O guess the file has tab space /t instead of the space

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Then is there a way I can split the string into two?

Comment: You have the answer. Use @Matthias answer

Answer (score 1):

I guess the file has tab space /t instead of the space